# EF connection string App vs Application Name

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

Do **App** and **Application Name** mean the same thing in an EF4 connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those properties of the ConnectionString in an EntityConnection are the same. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx).

> **App** - Synonym of Application Name.
>
> **Application Name** - The name of the application, or '.NET SQLClient Data Provider' if no application name is provided.
>   An application name can be 128 characters or less.